# Como crear variables auto-incrementales mediante ciclos

Tags: python

Quisiera saber si es posible crear variables auto-incrementales en python utilizando un ciclo como por ejemplo ciclo for:

**Ejemplo:**

Tenemos las variables (self,b1,self.b2,self.b3)

pero todas se conectan a una sola función, sera posible hacer algo como esto:

```
for i in range(3):
   self."b"+str(i).connect(lambda:self.función)

def funcion(self):
   pass
```

o como podria hacerlo sin necesidad de conectar manualmente cada variable o escribir cada una de ellas.

Comment: ¿PyQt o otro framework gráfico? Sería más fácil usar un contenedor como una lista para almacenar las referencias a los widgets en vez de usar variables. Se pueden crear o acceder a variables de forma dinámica haciendo uso de eval/exec pero es tremendamente poco legible y generalmente hay mejores formas de hacerlo...

Comment: @FJSevilla, de hecho ocupo pyqt5, y pues tengo 5 widgets que van desde self.b1 - self.b5 pero pues todas comparten una misma funcion y no quiero hacer de uno en uno la connexion con la funcion

Comment: Quizás podrías hacerlo con `setattr()`, pero es preferible que uses listas como te sugiere FJSevilla. Con `setattr()` sería algo como: `for i in range(3): setattr(self, "b"+str(i), XX)`, lo que crearía el atributo `b0`, `b1` y `b2` en `self`, con el valor inicial XX, pero ¿cuál sería XX en este caso? ¿Quizás un objeto tipo button? Si no no podrás hacer el `.connect()` seguidamente.